# работа с setState

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

как правильно прописать в сетСтейте на 31 строке, чтоб он брал значение с предыдущего состояния?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете получить в коллбэк предыдущее состояние.

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
  ...prevState,
  counter: prevState.counter + 1
}));
```

Пример: https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-snowflake-751ix?file=/src/App.js:207-304